# Problems with java PlainDocument overwriting values

Tags: java, jtextfield, uppercase

Good afternoon.
I am developing a screen where I have a **JTextField** which should always receive **UpperCase** values​​. Looking, i just created a class derived from **PlainDocument** treating it in **insertString**, and it worked.
The problem is that whenever I edit the value of my JTextField it will over-write the string instead of going in the middle of inserting string values ​​that I'm typing. Example: I have the value "**João da Silva**" in my field, and I want to add the name "**Pedro**" soon after "**João**" and before the "**da Silva**", but when I place the cursor at the position of the keyboard and I want to start enter it on-write string getting "**João Pedrolva**" instead of "**João Pedro da Silva**". I hope you have given to understand.
Anyone know how to fix this? I searched a lot and tried many ways but could not solve.

```
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

public class UpperCaseField extends JTextField {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UpperCaseField() {
        super();
    }

    protected Document createDefaultModel() {
        return new UpperCaseDocument();
    }

    static class UpperCaseDocument extends PlainDocument {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override 
        public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) 
            throws BadLocationException {

            if (str == null) {
                return;
            }
            char[] upper = str.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < upper.length; i++) {
                upper[i] = Character.toUpperCase(upper[i]);
            }
            super.insertString(offs, new String(upper), a);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
@Override 
public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) 
            throws BadLocationException {

   if (str == null) {
      return;
   }

   super.insertString(offs, str.toUpperCase(), a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But still the same =/ The UpperCase works ok, my problem is with the override of the value when insert a new char in middle of them.

Comment: The overwriting that you describe doesn't happen for me, nor does your code show anything that would make that happen.  Perhaps you have some sort of KeyListener or KeyBinding that's making it behave as you describe?  Post an SSCCE.

Answer (score 0):

Write your method this way:

```
@Override
public void insertString(int offset, String text, AttributeSet attributes) throws BadLocationException {

    if (text != null) {

        int currentBufferLength = getLength();
        String currentBufferContent = getText(0, currentBufferLength);

        String newText;

        if (currentBufferLength == 0) {
            newText = text;
        } else {
            newText = new StringBuilder(currentBufferContent)
                    .insert(offset, text)
                    .toString();
        }

        try {
                super.insertString(offset, text.toUpperCase(), attributes);
        } catch (BadLocationException exception) {
        }

    }
}
```

Sorry I haven't got time to explain. But, hopefully, you can see what you're doing wrong when you compare.